# grpc Trying to connect an http1.x server

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I have Node.js grpc server and Node.js grpc client. My grpc server is insecure server, and I already tested my grpc server using my client in local.

But I deployed to kube using nginx ingress controller and network load balancer then I got error.

```
{
  "error": "14 UNAVAILABLE: Trying to connect an http1.x server"
}
```

The odd thing is when I using [grpcurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl), then I could get success result.

I am using this script.

```
$ grpcurl -insecure -proto my.proto grpc.example.com my.grpc.package/service
```

Is it problem because of my server? Or my client is incorrect?

Comment: "Trying to connect an http1.x server" would be because the server responds with an HTTP/1 protocol response, which grpc clients don't support. There is a gRPC core library test that illustrates how this error intended to happen in such a case: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/5a419c65b02b069f4c92623678743a3ddddc53cb/test/core/end2end/bad_server_response_test.cc#L345.

Comment: Are both grpccurl and the grpc.js client going to the same endpoint?

Answer (score 5):

Usually that msg is result of using the wrong port.

In my case the service was :

```
NAME           TYPE         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE

foo-name      ClusterIP     10.0.8.132   <none>        5556/TCP,5557/TCP   123d
```

I was forwarding my port to 5556 and I got the same error msg.

I changed my port to forward from 5557 and it worked fine.

Comment: This weirdly enough worked, I changed my port from 8080 to something else and it worked

Comment: In my case port 8080 was in use so I switched ports and it worked.