# PHP GRPC Trying to connect an http1.x server

Tags: php, grpc

I'm facing a issue while I'm trying to use GRPC with PHP. Is there others persons that use GRPC with PHP ?

So I'm trying to implement GRPC communication in a PHP Symfony App.
My working env is a docker container and the GRPC server is online (dotnet hosted on Azure with AKS).

I have installed grpcurl inside the docker container to call my grpc service and it's working. But when I try to do it with PHP, It's not working and it returns the following: `error 14 : Trying to connect an http1.x server`

```
$client = new StockServiceClient('hostname:443', [
    'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()
]);
```

I have also tried to run the GRPC server on my local machine, and the code bellow is working.

```
$client = new StockServiceClient('host.docker.internal:9000', [
    'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()
]);
```

The server only listen for `HTTP2` on port `9000`.
When the server is hosted online, it's behind a reverse proxy with TLS and as I said, when I use Postman or grpcurl it works.

I don't know if is miss some additional configurations related to PHP FPM or grpc.so extension..

Comment: You are trying to connect to port `443` which is usually used for `SSL`, but then you are using a insecure channel? Have you seen the following questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475984/not-able-to-connect-to-grpc-from-nodejs-python-client) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644001/grpc-trying-to-connect-an-http1-x-server)

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks for your answer ! You are right. I thought that ChannelCredentials::createSsl was to provide SSL certificate to authenticate the client
Thanks a lot !